# How to put a certain number of files in one 'master' file

Tags: perl

I want to take all my log files from `/var/log` and `cat` them into a master log file, then zip that master file. How exactly would I do that?

I have `cat` in my code because that's what I know how to do in bash. How would I do it in Perl?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError);

# cat /var/log/*log > /home/glork/masterlog.log


my @files = </var/log/*.log>;
    zip \@files => 'glork.zip'
            or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";


@files = </var/log/*.log>;

if (@files) {
 unlink @files or warn "Problem unlinking @files: $!";
   print "The job is done\n";
  } else {
 warn "No files to unlink!\n";
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to put one file after another, or consolidate them into one file where the log messages of all of them are interleaved and sorted according to the timestamps? The `cat` command obviously won't work. Maybe you should change that in the question to be a comment, or you will have someone point out that it's wrong syntax.

Comment: I don't see the point in concatenating the files, it just loses information. Why not simply zip them all as separate files into a single zip file?

Comment: `tar cvfz logs.tar.gz /var/log/*log` is how I'd do it. No need for 'perl' at all. If you really need: `tar cvfz logs.tar.gz /var/log/*log && rm -f /var/log/*log`. If the problem is log consolidation, then I wouldn't do it this way either, I'd just look at changing the rsyslog.conf

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, there are several less involved ways to do this. If you really need to roll your own, [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.59/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) will do whatever you tell it to.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use Archive::Zip ':ERROR_CODES';
use File::Temp;
use Carp;

# don't remove "temp" files when filehandle is closed
$File::Temp::KEEP_ALL = 1;
# make a temp directory if not already present
my $dir = './tmp';
if (not -d $dir) {
  croak "failed to create directory [$dir]: $!" if not mkdir($dir);
}

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

# generate some fake log files to zip up
for my $idx (1 .. 10) {
  my $tmp = File::Temp->new(DIR => $dir, SUFFIX => '.log');
  my $fn = $tmp->filename();
  print $tmp $fn, "\n";
}

# combine the logs into one big one
my $combined = "$dir/combined.log";
open my $out, '>', $combined or die "couldn't write [$combined]: $!";
for my $fn (<$dir/*.log>) {
  open my $in, '<', $fn or die "couldn't read [$fn]: $!";
  # copy the file line by line so we don't use tons of memory for big files
  print($out $_) for <$in>;
}
close $out;

$zip->addFile({ filename => $combined, compressionLevel => 9});

# write out the zip file we made
my $rc = $zip->writeToFileNamed('tmp.zip');
if ($rc != AZ_OK) {
  croak "failed to write zip file: $rc";
}
```